# Yajra Datatable export all the records

Tags: export-to-csv, laravel-9, export-to-pdf, yajra-datatable

I am using yajra Datatable in laravel 9. I integrate their buttons like: copy, csv, excel, pdf, print.
When I want to export/print it just exports the records that are only visible to table (10 records).
But I want to export all the paginated records also. How can I do it? Can you give me any Solutions?

My Controller,

```
public function index(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $data = YajraDataTable::select('id','name','email','phone')->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>';
                    return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
        return view('admin.yajra.index');
    }
```

My Blade file,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var table = $('#user_datatable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                responsive: true,
                autoWidth:false,
                ajax: "{{ route('yajra.datatable') }}",
                columns: [
                    { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false },
                    {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                    {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                    {data: 'phone', name: 'phone'},
                    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                ],
                dom: 'lBfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    { extend: 'copy',  exportOptions: { modifier: { page: 'all', search: 'none' } } },
                    { extend: 'excel', exportOptions: { modifier: { page: 'all', search: 'none' } } },
                    { extend: 'csv',   exportOptions: { modifier: { page: 'all', search: 'none' } } },
                    { extend: 'pdf',   exportOptions: { modifier: { page: 'all', search: 'none' } } },
                    { extend: 'print', exportOptions: { modifier: { page: 'all', search: 'none' } } },
                    { extend: 'colvis', exportOptions: { modifier: { page: 'all', search: 'none' } } },
                ],
                "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All'] ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: In order to use Yajra with export functions, you will need to implement Yajra as a service.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but maybe it will help someone. As long as the data is not that much then do `serverSide: false` then you are good to go. I just did that and it is working.
The only problem is the performance issue.